# A question about up-voting questions

Tags: discussion

I am noticing a reluctance to up-vote questions lately.

Many times I am seeing a question which is quite good, good or very good and has received one two or three answers all of which have, themselves, been up-voted and sometimes an answer accepted by the OP.

It seems to me that there is a lack of encouragement being shown to that portion of users who ask most questions - namely, the most recent users to join the site.

Am I alone in noticing this trend ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not alone in observing a recent apparent reluctance to up-vote good questions although the fact your question has now attracted five up-votes might be the exception. I'm just sorry I didn't notice this question till now!

While I think it is a positive move to award good questions 10 points as an incentive to ask more questions, it may be that new users need a bit of time to get to grips with what constitutes a "good question".  Asking a well-researched question takes time and effort.  That is why good questions should be rewarded.

A possible explanation for a shortage of good questions from new users is that some come from question and answer sites that are extremely lax with regard to what can be asked and no prior research or evidence to substantiate claims is expected.  I suspect that some new users are quickly discouraged when they realise some effort is required on their part!

There is another possible explanation for good questions not attracting up-votes that has nothing to do with new users.  Competitiveness and a desire to keep oneself ahead in the weekly, monthly, quarterly and annual listings. I sincerely hope I am wrong about that!